# Set default for class member function's struct input

Tags: c++, struct, default

I have the following code, and would like to give default value for param3. I have tried various attempts, and compiler's error msg seems to be saying in class non-int initialization is not allowed.
Is this a bad practice and why? What's a better approach from a OO perspective?
thanks

```
struct MyStruct 
{ 
    int a; 
    int b;
};
class myClass {
    public:
        void init(int param1 = 0, int param2 = 0, MyStruct param3);
}
```

Comment: If you have access to C++11, I believe that you can use any `constexpr` expression as a default parameter value.

Comment: Show us how you tried to give the default argument.

Comment: void init(int param1 = 0, int param2 = 0, MyStruct param3 = {0,0});

Comment: Compile with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: `MyStruct param3 = MyStruct()`

Comment: I'm using g++, how do I add the "-std=c++11" switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a constructor and a default constructor  `MyStruct` and make a constant default value like this:

```
struct MyStruct { 
    int a; 
    int b;
    MyStruct(int x, int y):a(x), b(y) {} // Constrctor.
    MyStruct():a(0), b(0) {}             // Default constrctor.
};

const MyStruct default_(3, 4);           // for instance here by default a == 3 and b == 4

class myClass {
    public:
        void init(int param1 = 0, int param2 = 0, MyStruct param3 = default_);
};
```

Comment: This seems to work if I use 
    const MyStruct default_ = {3,4};
FYI, I do not have control over MyStruct, do I could not add the constructor. The folks who implemented  MyStruct used a strict C fashion struct.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work (at least with C++11):

```
void init(int param1 = 0, int param2 = 0, MyStruct param3 = MyStruct{ 2, 3 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest and clearest way to solve a problem like this would be to do something like this:

```
class myClass {
  public:
    void init(int p1 = 0, int p2 = 0)
    {
       MyStruct s; //initialize this to whatever default values
       init(p1, p2, s);
    }
    void init(int p1, int p2, MyStruct p3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in C++0x.

```
struct MyStruct 
{ 
    int a; 
    int b;
};

function foo(int a, structure s = structure{10,20}) 
{
    //Code
}
```